# Converting cURL to angular

Tags: angular, authentication, curl, zendesk

I have the cURL command that works great:

```
curl https://{{mydomain}}.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json \
  -d '{"ticket": {"subject": "Testing!", "type":"problem", "priority":"low", "custom_fields": [{"id": 25227383, "value": "support"}, {"id": 24746086, "value": "customer"}, {"id": 24621686, "value": "product"}, {"id": 24462503, "value": "yes"}], "comment": { "body": "Description" }}}' \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v -u {{email}}/token:{{token}} https://obscura.zendesk.com/api/v2/users.json
```

And I tried to convert it to this in angular 5:

```
const body = {"ticket": 
{"subject": "Testing!",
"type":"problem", 
"priority":"low", 
"custom_fields": 
[{"id": 25227383, "value": "support"},
{"id": 24746086, "value": "customer"}, 
{"id": 24621686, "value": "product"}, 
{"id": 24462503, "value": "yes"}], 
"comment": { "body": "Description" }}};

this.http.post('https://{{mydomain}}.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json', 
{data: body,
headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Authorization': 'Bearer {{email}}/token:{{token}}',
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}})
.toPromise().then(function(response) {
console.log(response.toString());
})
```

I'm getting the errors as below:

```
POST https://{{mydomain}}.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json 401 (Unauthorized)

Failed to load https://{{mydomain}}.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 0 for URL: null
at resolvePromise (zone.js:824)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
at eval (zone.js:873)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4620)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:503)
at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)
```

I assume that something is wrong with my authentication.

Does someone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You might want to make sure you're using OAuth authentication per ZenDesk's documentation:
https://help.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005580188-Making-cross-origin-browser-side-API-requests

They do not allow cross origin requests using basic authentication or an API token.

Comment: Correct, request should be made via the server, to protect the token being exposed in the client side.

Answer (score 1):

When you make an Http request directly using CURL, Postman, or something like that you don't  need to set the CORS header.  but now that you are making an Ajax  call from your web app(Angular) you  are making the request from another domain clocalhost) so you should set the header:
       Access-Control-Allow-Origin
in your request. Also usually you  need such configuration on the SERVER  side as well  which again usually is done through  a config file.